# Will 1600mhz DDR3 ram work with 1333mhz?

Tags: memory

So I am kind of in a pickle, i'm extremely new to hardware upgrading and I came upon a issue.

My computer currently has 2x2GB sticks of: Elpida PC3-10600 ram  ([https://www.amazon.com/Elpida-PC3-10600-1333mhz-NON-ECC-EBJ21UE8BDF0-DJ-F/dp/B0125BC7SE](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0125BC7SE))

I would like to upgrade to 8 GB, so I purchased two of these: ValueSelect 2GB DDR3 1333MHz CL9 RAM Stick, however after I inserted the sticks into my motherboard it refused to boot, I have verified my ram slots are working so I assume the memory is incompatible with my chipset.

I decided to use Crucials System Scan tool and it recommends me to use: Crucial 2GB DDR3-1600 UDIMM (http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/thinkcentre-m58p-(type--7347,-7357,-7358,-7483,-7484,-7630,-7635,-9964-and-9965)/CT5509224)

However this doesn't make any sense to me, why is Crucial Recommending me DDR3 PC3-12800 while I currently have PC3-10600 installed? Will this even work in my system and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off mixing ram can potentially damage your computer (especially different speed and brand) so don't try it if you can avoid it. Although I have mixed ram myself and personally did not have any problems.

1) You need to make sure that your motherboard first supports the ram you are using

2) Make sure you are putting the ram in the correct slots, sounds to me you have 2 dual channel sets, make sure you put each set in the respective dual channel slots (usually colour coded).

3) Check BIOS if the motherboard is even detecting the ram

Crucial is probably assuming you're buying completely new set of ram so recommending a different speed.

Comment: 1) The ram I tried to use (ValueSelect 2GB DDR3 1333MHz) claims it is for all Intel platforms, so it is supported.

2) Yes, I have confirmed i'm putting the ram pairs in the respective color coded slot

3) Computer won't boot at all, cannot access BIOS when the new ram sticks are inserted.

Comment: Does the computer boot if you only use the new ram? If so, the ram sticks are not compatible and you should probably stop using them together. Otherwise, you might have faulty ram.

Comment: I have tried that aswell, put the new ram in the existing slots of my old ram. The computer still does not boot.

Comment: Yea, either ram is faulty, or your motherboard doesn't support it.

Comment: Well I purchased 2 x 2GB of ram sticks chances of them both being faulty should be slim, and I dont know why my motherboard wouldn't support it , the manufacturer claims it should work and i'm using nearly identical specifications as my previous ram sticks. Thanks for your help so far, but i'm stuck lol

Comment: *> mixing ram can potentially damage your computer (especially different speed and brand)* [citation needed]

Answer (score 0):

They will work with the slower memory speed but you can use them.

Comment: This information is already given in the linked answer. Please refrain from posting an answer if you will only be duplicating information already posted.

Answer (score -1):

It could work, but if you want to be really sure, and assure stability, you should use sticks with identical speeds

Comment: That's the thing though, I did stick to the speed before and used this ram: http://www.memoryexpress.com/Products/MX64936 but it didnt work. So i don't know what to do.

Comment: DO you have dual channel memory?

Comment: CPU-Z reports I do have Dual Channel

Comment: check the answer below it says everything i have to say